# Symfony/Twig : print a function return in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, service, twig

I'd like to do something like :

```
{{ users_number() }} or {{ users_number }}
```

in a Twig's template. My service looks like this :

```
class HomeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
 {
   public function getFunction()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('users_number', array($this, 'getUsersNb'))
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'users_number';
    }

    public function getUsersNb(){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $countUsers = $em->getRepository("ASDPUsersBundle:Users")->getNb();
        return $countUsers;
    }
}
```

Still, i can't get my value in my view.
How could i do it ? Or did i miss something in my service ?

Edit:
I registered my service like this :

```
services:
 users_number:
  class: ASDP\HomeBundle\Twig\Extension\HomeExtension
  tags:
   - { name : twig.extension }
```

Is it the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('users_number', array($this,'getUsersNb')))
    );
}
```

And your extension must extend \Twig_Extension and service must have tag twig.extension :

```
<service class="Vendor\Bundle\Twig\Extension\YourExtension" id="your.extension.id">
  <tag name="twig.extension"/>
</service>
```

OR in Yaml:

```
your.extension.id:
    class: Vendor\Bundle\Twig\Extension\YourExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: I tried with your changes but i still got the same error and can't reach my users_number function (i added my service to the original post)

Comment: @VincentEstrany can you add here whole extension class?

Comment: @VincentEstrany change getFunction on getFunctions and it will be working :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the entity manager on your Twig Extension Service

```
your.extension.id:
    class: Vendor\Bundle\Twig\Extension\YourExtension
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

And then use it in your custom extension:

```
protected $em;

public function __construct($em)
{
    $this->translator = $translator;
}

// ...

public function getUsersNb()
{
    $countUsers = $this->em->getRepository("ASDPUsersBundle:Users")->getNb();
    return $countUsers;
}
```

I hope it helps.